# bulk file upload validation with zip file

Tags: java

I am doing bulk file upload in Struts2. My questions are below.

1. How do I validate or scan file types inside a zipped file whilst uploading(I want to check for .exe files inside the zip folder), using JavaScript or jQuery or Java.
2. Once zipped file uploaded successfully, zipped file should be extracted to the destination path.
3. Unique reference no. should generate for each file which is extracted from uploaded zipped file.

Answer (score 0):

Apache [ZipUtil](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipUtil.html) should help you achieve all you want to do. Hope you should be able to use the API and code as per your requirement.